# mapping regular class objects to MVC model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

we are converting asp.net to MVC. we have a framework and it returns regular class objects or datasets. what is the best way to map class object to MVC model? please let me know.

for example,

```
//framework class
public class ISTApplicant
{
   public ISTApplicant GetApplicant()
   { 
       ISTApplicant objApplicant = new ISTApplicant();
       return objApplicant;
   }

   public Dataset GetApplicants()
   {
       return ds;
   }
}
```

## MVC Model

```
public class ApplicantModel
{
    public string CustomerNo { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<ApplicantModel> LstApplicantModel { get; set; }
}
```

## Controller class

```
public class ApplicantController : Controller
{
    //how can i assign framework object to my model, something like this.  
    public ActionResult GetApplicant()
    {  
        ApplicantModel model = myframework.Applicant.GetApplicant();
        return mode;
    }

    public ActionResult GetApplicants()
    {
         //if it is dataset what is the best way to handle?
         LstApplicantModel list =  myframework.GetApplicants();
         return list;
    }
}
```

you might see some errors since I typed it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things in your code that will not compile. Also, be aware of the indent spaces in order to make your code more readable.

Assuming that you have created an action in your controller properly and **ISTApplicant** has the same fields than **ApplicantModel** you can do something like this:

In your **Startup.cs** file:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<ISTApplicant, ApplicantModel>();
});
```

Then, in your controller:

```
public ActionResult GetApplicant() 
{
    ISTApplicant db = myframework.Applicant.GetApplicant();
    ApplicantModel model = Mapper.Map<ApplicantModel>(db);
    return model;
}
```

The above example is using [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper). Please look how to configure it and how to add the dependency on each controller properly.

I didn't modify the example by adding the list property that you mentioned because you should create another action to do this with similar logic involved.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.  my manager wont accept using 3 rd party tools. what do you think about c# implicit/explicit operators. i implemented one class with this and it is good. but dont know it is a best practice.  also about datasets, i see extension methods DataTableToList, not sure it is good to use. please reply.

Comment: I don't think it is a good practice. If you want  another option would be passing your DB model to the constructor of you MVC Model and do all the mappings there, but I still prefer using a framework. If you're using MVC Core, this is available by default and you don't have to include any Nu-Get package. Read about that, it will simplify a lot the task of mapping your objects.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the problem that AutoMapper solves:
https://automapper.org/

If you define your new MVC models to use the same property names & types as your existing framework models then you can easily transform one to the other, otherwise it's simple enough to define explicit mappings for individual properties.

The documentation at the above link is pretty good, so no need to repeat it here, but it's worth pointing out that mapping configurations are directional in terms of 'from' and 'to' object types.

For example if you are returning objects from a database and then submitting updated versions from the MVC application, you will need separate mappings to go from type A to type B and also from type B back to type A.

Comment: There are other mappers out there (like TinyMapper) but I like AutoMapper the best.